# spring.config.import reference to application.yaml in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an Springboot application, the Jar includes an `application.yaml` with set of configuration

```yaml
management:
  server.port: 9420
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /actuator
      exposure:
        include: "health,liveness,env"
  endpoint:
     health:
       probes:
         enabled: true
```

The application is deployed in Kubernetes, set of data is added in `ConfigMap` resource. The ConfigMap is mounted as volume in deployment to `/opt/config/app/application.yaml`

```yaml
management:
  server.port: 9415
```

- The Spring application started with below command

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.import=/opt/config/app/application.yaml --logging.config=/opt/config/log/logback.xml
```

Question:

- since the jvm argument `--spring.config.import` is passed with the application.yaml, will the data in this file will override the file within the jar file?

Will the `mangement.server.port = 9145` will be used from the configMap and rest form the application.yaml of jar file.